# DefaultRowSorter Causing java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid range

Tags: java, swing

I have read other topics related to this issue but this one seems to be slightly different.

I have followed the way to create a defaultrowsorter here.

http://zawoad.blogspot.com/2009/02/filter-jtable-row-with-input-in-text.html

Seems to be ok when i do a series model.addRow but when i do a series of model.setValueAt() i eventually get the following error

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid range
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.checkAgainstModel(DefaultRowSorter.java:921)
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.rowsUpdated(DefaultRowSorter.java:894)
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.rowsUpdated(DefaultRowSorter.java:915)
at javax.swing.JTable.notifySorter(JTable.java:4264)
at javax.swing.JTable.sortedTableChanged(JTable.java:4118)
at javax.swing.JTable.tableChanged(JTable.java:4395)
at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableChanged(AbstractTableModel.java:296)
at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableCellUpdated(AbstractTableModel.java:275)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:666)
```

Anyone have a clue as to why this is happening? Did i miss something perhaps not mentioned in the tutorial in the link?

Comment: `Did i miss something perhaps not mentioned in the tutorial in the link?` - Well the logical answer to that question would be yes, since you are getting an exception. However, we are not mind readers.  We have no idea what you might be missing because you haven't posted any code!!! Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. Chances are while you create the SSCCE you will find your problem. I would suggest you start with the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for a complete demo.

Comment: Are you modifying your model outside of the event dispatch thread?  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html